# How do I find the new position of a feature after undistorting the image?

Tags: c++, opencv, camera

I have an image with a circle in it, and I use the openCV methods to detect it and display its edges and center on the image before the image is rectified and undistorted.

I rectify the image and undistort it using InitUndistortRectifyMap in OpenCV. After remaping,  the image is warped and the circle has an oval shape due to the change in perspective. The position coordinates of the center do obviuosly change as well.

I  cannot do the circle detection step after rectifying because this will produce inaccurate results, due to the perspective change.

My question is, how can I find the position of the center after the image has been undistorted and rectified?

Answer (score 2):

There is an [undistortPoints](http://docs.opencv.org/modules/imgproc/doc/geometric_transformations.html#undistortpoints) function which is able to transform vector of Point2f or Point2d.

Comment: How is this useful?? The whole image is rectified and warped. That's the main problem. The effect of undistortion is minimal.

Comment: @user1901213 I think the answer is explaining how you can compute the location of the center...which is exactly your question?